# Regex to match all numbers except for 0, 1 (11, 12, etc.) included

Tags: regex

I need to capture all numbers after the first hashtag which is larger than 1, but can't grab 10-19. The expression looks like this: `randomstring#11#1#0`

Currently, I came up with:

```
^[^#\s]+#[^0-1]\d*#.+$
```

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: thank you for suggestions. I want to exclude expressions, with number higher than 1 after first hash.

Comment: As spelled out in the [tag:regex] tag info, please spell out which regex engine you are using. The use of `\s` and `\d` suggests that you are using a PCRE-style regex engine which has features like lookaheads and named groups, but there are more POSIX-like regex engines which have `\s` and `\d` but lack those features.

Comment: "can't grab" as in "mustn't", or "am currently unable to"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To match any number larger than 1 that is preceded by a hash character, you may use a Lookbehind as follows:

```
(?<=#)(?:[1-9]\d+|[2-9])
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/axZ9J0/1)**.

**Breakdown:**

- `(?<=#)` - A Lookbehind to ensure the match is preceded by "#".
- `(?:` - Start a non-capturing group.

  - `[1-9]\d+` - Match any number consisting of two or more digits not starting with a zero.
  - `|` - OR...
  - `[2-9]` - Match any number between 2 and 9.
- `)` Close the non-capturing group.

If Lookbehind isn't supported, you may use:

```
#([1-9]\d+|[2-9])
```

..and the number will be in group 1.

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/LFwTSQ/1)**.

Comment: yes, thats what I needed (2nd regex). Kudos to you.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a more POSIX-y variant.

```
^[^#]*#(1[0-9]+|[2-9][0-9]*)
```

The parentheses will capture the number and the expression as a whole will match the first occurrence of `#` if it is followed by these digits.  The first `^` matches beginning of line and `[^#]*` will match any sequence of characters which are not `#`.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/0Nsxdf/1

Comment: It works for the first number, without the `^[^#]*` it will work for all numbers :-)